# How can i remove a item from a combobox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Here's my situation,
I have to make a program that helps the management of the World Cup 2018 of Soccer, i have to add teams, players, games, etc.
So, when i gonna to register a game, i have a combobox with all the Eliminations of the cup. So, when i register the first game of the Eight Finals the window close for me to add another Eight Final. So, basically i want to remove from the combobox the game i chosen before..
I try the comboBoxGame.Items.Remove(comboboxGame.SelectedItem) but i think, because of the windows close up, the item dont remove from the combobox..
Can somoene help me ?
PS: sorry for my bad english ...

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, because i didnt use DataSource.. I'm a begginer at this, so i dont even know how to use DataSource

Comment: Please include more code - it is hard to give advice without seeing more of your code. Including how you populate the combo box.

Comment: OK! So, i populate my combobox on Unbound Mode in that pop-up window called String Collection Editor. I don't know what part of the code you want... I can be more especific. After open the form, then dropdown the list and i chose the "1º Eight-Final", when i finish the events of the game i register the winner in a list and the form shuts down. When i open again the form, i want to remove the "1º Eight-Final" item from the combobox...

Comment: @BernardoPratas SO has tons of questions related to how to remove items and that question has one answer that spells it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You've mentioned that you use String Collection Editor**

**String Collection Editor** Allows you to pre-set a list of strings for a some Controls incl. ComboBox, which means that with any run-time initialization of the Control, those strings that you have set through the String Collection Editor will be added to it.

**How it can be solved? -** the simplest way would probably be to use a DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try:
When you open your program the combobox's data load from a xml file,when you  close the program,the combobox's data save to the xml file.